# Why did he visit the gift shop?

Tags: plot-explanation, three-billboards-outside-ebbing

A guy came into the gift shop where Mildred was working and spoke with her about maybe being the person who murdered her daughter. Later, he

> bragged that he raped someone while setting the victim on fire. It turned out he wasn't the guy who murdered Mildred's daughter.

But why did he came into the gift shop and say such things?

Answer (score 2):

Later in the movie, Dixon overhears the guy talking about something that sounds like the core crime of the movie.  Dixon gets some of his dna and gets it tested, only to turn out that there was no dna match.  We also learn that the guy was military and was deployed to a classified location at the time of the murder, so it couldn't have been him.

My interpretation is that this man, having seen the billboards on the news, took it as an attack on authority figures, such as the police and the military.  He went and intimidated Mildred to try and show her not to test these authority figures, and might have been considering other things before he was interrupted.

Comment: Why would he side with the police, if he himself is a criminal who committed the same crime as mentioned on the billboards?

Comment: @TK-421 to be honest, we don't know if what he was talking about really was a crime or not, there's just not enough information given with the conversation that we hear.  if it was a crime, it seems that he has some clout in the military and things might be getting covered up for him.  we just don't know, and that's the point

Comment: I am more interested about why he came and said the things in the gift shop, rather than what he said later at the bar.